# Checkbox value doesnt show when a customer is clicked

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am echoing to my website possible checkbox values that are in a table JobChoose like this

```
<?php
$got = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM JobChoose");
$checkbox = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($got)) {
    $checkbox .= '<li><input type="checkbox" id="Jobselect" name="Job" value = "' . $row['Job'] . '">' . $row['Job'] . '</input></li>';
} ?> 

<?php echo $checkbox;?>
```

When a checkbox is selected is inserted to a customer info.
But when i am trying to to get selected value back nothing appears when i click to a customer although it appears in mysql database

```
echo "<td align='center' class='hidden'>". $row["Job"] ."</td>";

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#tabled').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $("#Jobselect").val($(this).find("td").eq(19).html());
    });
</script>
```

Also i fetch search results into a table like this

```
<?php


  $sql = "SELECT * FROM new_record WHERE surname LIKE
 '%".$_POST["search"]."%' or name LIKE'%".$_POST["search"]."%' or
 barcode LIKE'%".$_POST["search"]."%'";    $result =
 mysqli_query($connect, $sql);    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)    {


     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

                       echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td >". $row["id"] ."</td>";
                       echo "<td>". $row["surname"] ."</td>";
                      echo "<td>". $row["name"] ."</td>";
                      echo "<td>". $row["company_name"] ."</td>";
                      echo "<td>". $row["firm"] ."</td>";
                        echo "<td>". $row["address"] ."</td>";
                      echo "<td>". $row["town"] ."</td>";
                        echo "<td>". $row["tk"] ."</td>";
                          echo "<td>". $row["country"] ."</td>";
                          echo "<td>". $row["telephone"] ."</td>";
                         echo "<td>". $row["fax"] ."</td>";
                           echo "<td>". $row["mobile"] ."</td>";
                             echo "<td>". $row["mail"] ."</td>";
                               echo "<td>". $row["web_site"] ."</td>";
                               echo "<td>". $row["barcode"] ."</td>";
                         echo "<td>". $row["visitors"] ."</td>";
                             echo "<td align='center' class='hidden'>". $row["custId"] ."</td>";
                           echo "<td align='center' class='hidden'>". $row["trn_date"] ."</td>"; echo "<td align='center' class='hidden'>".
 $row["HowToFindUs"] ."</td>"; echo "<td align='center'
 class='hidden'>". $row["Job"] ."</td>";
                       echo "</tr>";
       }    }    else    {  
       echo 'Data Not Found';    }    ?>
```

Comment: Please paste your complete code.

Comment: You really shouldn't use mysql_* functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: All your checkboxes have the same name `name="Job"` they all need a unique name OR use `name="Job[]"` to make the result sent to the form be an array of the checked checkboxes

Comment: '<li><input type="checkbox" id="Jobselect" name="Job"  checked = "checked" value = "' . $row['Job'] . '">' . $row['Job'] . '</input></li>'  add checked attribute to checkbox

Comment: Also all the checkboxes have the same `id="Jobselect"` Thats just illegal HTML code as an `id` on a page must also be UNIQUE of it will only see the last one. Also javascript wont like that

Comment: @RiggsFolly is inserting to db Array in info insted of the value

Comment: `$("#Jobselect")` will only know about the LAST `<input` tag that was put on the page with that ID, so that code will only ever address your last checkbox

Comment: @Kaushalshah checked="checked" is making all values that appear on checkox list checked

Comment: you have set atribute checked in jquery if else condition like this if($(this).is(':checked')){( this ).attr( 'checked', true ); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get selected checkbox value you should try below code :

```
<?php
$got = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM JobChoose");
$checkbox = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($got)) {
    $checkbox .= '<li><input type="checkbox" name="Job[]" value = "' . $row['Job'] . '">' . $row['Job'] . '</input></li>';
} ?> 

<?php echo $checkbox;?>
```

Here in your case you have place id for all checkboxes are same which was not correct.

Also in JS you should try below code :

```
echo "<td align='center' class='hidden'>". $row["Job"] ."</td>";

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
            if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                alert($(this).val());
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Please try this.

Comment: JobChoose is another table that possible jobs are echoed to html . Checkbox value is inserted on table named new_record that has a Job cell to store checked value.Then when i search a customer appear a table with matched customer and all information are filled to input form when i click to table row, all except checkbox value

Comment: It alerts me with the value of checked checkbox

Comment: Can you please tell me that what you want to alert ?

Comment: i dont want to alert something i want the value of the checkbox that was inserted to customer info be echoed in checkboxlist when i search for him again

Comment: And when i manage to insert multiple checkboxes my db table shows Array

Answer (score 0):

Solved !!!

I passed data to table with

> echo "". $row["Job"] ."";

And then

> $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){ var str =
>   $('#check').val(); var strarray = str.split(',');
>   if($.inArray($(this).val(),strarray)!=-1){
>   $(this).prop("checked","checked"); } else {
>   $(this).prop("checked",""); } });